# Where is the flaw in my algorithm to find the size of smallest substring containing an exact character set?

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, time-complexity

The setup is that I have a string like

```
s = "GAAATAAA"
```

and a dictionary like

```
surpdic = { 'A' -> 4 }
```

The meaning of the dictionary is that `s` has `4` surplus `A` characters.

What my algorithm seeks to find is the size of the smallest substring of `s` that contains `4` `A`s. I can't figure out why it is not working all of the test cases.

It's supposed to work like

```
GAAATAAA
 ||| |||
 i|| j||  j - i = 4, mindiff = 4
  ||  ||
  i|  j|  j - i = 4, mindiff = 4
   |   | 
   i   j  j - i = 4, mindiff = 4
```

on the example I provided. In other words, from left to right in the string, find the first span that contains all the characters, then effectively take out the left pointer and move it to the the beginning of the next possible span; all the while keep track of the minimum span.

```
int mindiff = Int32.MaxValue; 
int left = 0; 
while(!surpdic.ContainsKey(s[left++]));
for(int right = left; right < s.Length; ++right) 
{                   
    if(surpdic.ContainsKey(s[right])) 
        surpdic[s[right]] -= 1; 
    if(surpdic.Values.All(count => count == 0)) 
    {
        int diff = right - left; 
        if(diff < mindiff) 
            mindiff = diff;

        surpdic[s[left]] += 1; 
        while(!surpdic.ContainsKey(s[left++])); 
    }
}
```

**Edit:** So here's a case that is giving me a runtime error.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Solution
{   

    static int SmallestSubstringContainingChars(string source, Dictionary<char,int> surpdic)
    {
        int mindiff = Int32.MaxValue; 
        int left = 0; 
        while(!surpdic.ContainsKey(source[left++]));
        for(int right = left; right < source.Length; ++right) 
        {                   
            if(surpdic.ContainsKey(source[right])) 
                surpdic[source[right]] -= 1; 
            if(surpdic.Values.All(count => count == 0)) 
            {
                int diff = right - left; 
                if(diff < mindiff) 
                    mindiff = diff;

                surpdic[source[left]] += 1; 
                while(!surpdic.ContainsKey(source[left++])); 
            }
        }
        return mindiff + 1;
    }

    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "ACTGATTT";
        Dictionary<char,int> d = new Dictionary<char,int>() { { 'A' , 1 }, { 'T' , 3 } };
        Console.WriteLine( SmallestSubstringContainingChars(s,d));
    }
}
```

Comment: good fit for codereview.stackexhange

Comment: It might help to show us the test cases, both those working and those failing.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Pretty sure the folks at CR only take code that already works. [See here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I've gotta be honest, I've got no idea what you are trying to do here.

Comment: You should limit the `left` max value, otherwise your `while` loop may run forever.

Comment: From the description i did not understand what you are trying to find out.

Comment: "the smallest substring of s that contains 4 As" . That means in your posted string `s` you would find none. Is that right?

Comment: @MongZhu I mean the smallest substrings containing exactly 4As and any number of other characters

Comment: @MongZhu for what I understood, it doesn't need to be 4 consecutive "A"s, so in OP's post, it would be "AAATA"

Comment: Correcting my previous comment, it wouldn't run forever, but throw an exception when `left` becomes greater or equals to the string's size

Comment: ahhh! so like:  "AATAA" or "AAATA" or "ATAAA". what do you do with multiple occurances ?

Comment: The runtime error is because the way you're incrementing `left`. When you found a letter that is in the dictionary, you increment the index, so you're try to access the 'C' char in the dictionary (which is not in the dic). Try to change your while to while (!surpdic.ContainsKey(source[left]))
   {
    if (left == (source.Length - 1))
     break;
    left++;
   }

Answer (score 0):

I found many problems in your code.

First the way you were incrementing left.

Also, you are modifying the dictionary, so the next executions would start with a wrong dictionary, this is why I am creating a copy.

Don't decrement the dictionary entry if its value is already 0, otherwise your `All` code will not work.

Check the code below and if you don't understand anything, comment below. It will return -1 if the desired pattern is not found:

```
static int SmallestSubstringContainingChars(string source, Dictionary<char, int> surpdic)
{
    int mindiff = -2;

    int left = 0;
    while (left<source.Length)
    {
        if (surpdic.ContainsKey(source[left]))
        {
            Dictionary<char, int> md = new Dictionary<char, int>(surpdic);
            md[source[left]] -= 1;
            for (int right = left; right < source.Length; ++right)
            {
                if (md.ContainsKey(source[right]) && md[source[right]]>0)
                    md[source[right]] -= 1;
                if (md.Values.All(count => count == 0))
                {
                    int diff = right - left;
                    if (mindiff==-2 || diff < mindiff)
                        mindiff = diff;
                }
            }
        }
        left++;
    }
    return mindiff + 1;
}
```